# filter a json output of unknown depths in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Inputs = JSON string, list to filter the string.

output = Filtered dictionary

---

The input is a list which contains some valid and some invalid keys with nesting denoted by '.',
eg: `b.c.d` means the value of `d` in `{b: {c: { d: ...}}`

I want to filter the JSON string as per the query list and ignore any key which is not present.
eg: `b.c.j` should return nothing because it doesn't exist.

```
input_query_list = ["a", "b.c", "b.d.f", "g", "b.c.j"]


 json_string = """
        {
         "a": 1,
         "b": {
              "c" : 2,
              "d" : {
                      "e" : 3
                       "f" : ..... (unknown depth)
                     }
              },
         "g": "url",
          ... (Unknown depth)
        }"""

output = 
{
 "a": 1,
 "c": 2,
 "f": {...},
 "g": "url"
}
```

Current Code: This returns an error, when key is not in json. eg: b.c.j

```
json_string = """{ "a": 1, "b":{ "c" :2, "d" : { "e" : 3, "f" :4 } }, "g": 10 }"""
input_query_list = ["a", "b.c", "b.d.f", "g", "b.c.j"]

def parse_nested(list1, new_json_str):
  val = {}
  new_json_str = json.loads(json.dumps(new_json_str))
  for k in list1:
    print(f"k={k} json:{json.dumps(new_json_str, indent=4, sort_keys=True)}")
    if k in new_json_str and len(new_json_str) > 1:
      if list1[-1] in new_json_str:
        val = {list1[-1]:new_json_str[list1[-1]]}
        print("return val=",val)
        return val
      val = {k : new_json_str[k]}
      new_json_str= new_json_str[k]
    else:
      break
  print("return val=",val)
  return val


def parse_json(json_string, input_query_list):
  val = ""
  for key in input_query_list:
    if '.' in key:
      # print("key=",key)
      l1 = key.split('.')
      val = parse_nested(l1, json_string)
      if val:
        dict1.update(val)
    else:
      dict1.update({key:json_string[key]})

parse_json(json_string, input_query_list)
# print("\n\n\n")
print("output=",json.dumps(dict1, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

*What would be the best approach to solve this using python ?*

Comment: I assume you have unit tests for this already?

Comment: in your example `input_query_list`, shouldn't `b.d.e.f` instead be `b.d.f`?

Comment: Are you guaranteed there are no overlaps? What if you have `"a"` and `"b.a"` for the object `{"a":1, "b": {"a": 2}}` Why not just preserve the fact that you have `"b.a"` as a key? Dots are valid in dictionary keys

Comment: The keys in my case are unique header fields, hence no overlap.

Corrected the case for b.d.e.f to b.d.f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> returns an error, when key is not in json. eg: b.c.j

Hint: Do not use `[key]` notation for JSON access. Use the `.get(key, default=None)` method. This way, you can pass in an empty `dict()` as a default, and as you access this empty dict, you get no results back for further `.get()` calls.

Hint 2: Try to use recursion instead of a loop for unknown depths. This algorithm will closely match depth-first-search. Once you reach the terminal node, return the result back to the calling function.

As an example,

```
def parse_nested(find_key, data):
  keys = None
  nested_key = '.' in find_key
  if nested_key:  # start by splitting, if needed
    keys = find_key.split('.')
    find_key = keys[0]

  if not nested_key:  # base condition = no nesting
    if isinstance(data, dict):  # if the data we parsed into is a dictionary
      return data.get(find_key, None)  # get the key, if there, else None
    else:  # the data is not a dict, so there is no key to access
      return None 
  else:  # our key to find is not directly, so keep looking
    if find_key in data:  # if the first part is in the data, then we can keep going
      return parse_nested('.'.join(keys[1:]), data[find_key])
    else:  # Dead end; data is nested, but we cannot keep going from here
      return None
```

#### Result

```
data = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c" : 2,
    "d" : {
            "e" : 3,
              "f" : {}
            }
    },
  "g": "url",
  "j":  {}
}

keys = ["a", "b.c", "b.d.f", "g", "b.c.j"]
output = {k : parse_nested(k, data) for k in keys}
print(output)
```

Output

`{'a': 1, 'b.c': 2, 'b.d.f': {}, 'g': 'url', 'b.c.j': None}`

To sanitize the output,

`{k.split('.')[-1]:v for k,v in output.items() if v is not None}`

Resulting in `{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'f': {}, 'g': 'url'}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `glom`

- https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- pip install glom

```
import json
from glom import glom

info = json.loads(json_string)
input_query_list = ["a", "b.c", "b.d.f", "g", "b.c.j"]
for query in input_query_list:
    print(f'{query:>10} | {glom(info, query, default=None)}')
```

gives

```
         a | 1
       b.c | 2
     b.d.f | .....
         g | url
     b.c.j | None
```

Cleaned up `json_string` from your question, for reference:

```
json_string = """\
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c": 2,
    "d": {
      "e": 3,
      "f": "....."
    }
  },
  "g": "url"
}"""
```

If you really decide you want the output you suggest (which I recommend against, it is not generally safe, and doesn't make sense - many inputs can map to the same outputs, others can be discarded).  You can do it with a simple filtering, inline checks, post-processing, `KeyError`s or whatever you want:

```
no_match = object()
output = {}
for query in input_query_list:
    result = glom(info, query, default=no_match)
    if result is not no_match:  # save a KeyError
        last_attr = query.split('.')[-1]
        output[last_attr] = result
```

giving

```
assert output == {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'f': '.....', 'g': 'url'}
```